# Is debugging helpful?

Tags: debugging

I've been programming for about 5 months now. I started with C++ then C and finally Java. In this time I have never used the debugging feature on my compilers, nor do I know what it does. In class I have been taught nothing about the debugger so far (Altho class is barely starting in C, I learned C++ and Java on my own). What is debugging, what does it do and do you use it often? What are the uses for debugging? I've googled debugging, but I couldn't quite understand. Can anyone explain the debugging feature properly? From what I understand so far, it's a feature to help you find bugs, but I don't quite get how it works.

Comment: you can follow your code execution step by step. It's useful in finding and troubleshooting bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debugging itself is the process of finding and exterminating bugs, nothing more and nothing less. So unless you're a perfect programmer who never makes any mistakes, you've done it.

A *debugger*, on the other hand, is a tool which assists in debugging. You can still debug without a debugger, but using a debugger gives you more options, and ways to go about it.

Without you mentioning specifically which debugger you're talking about (Visual Studio one, or gdb, or...) we can't really tell you how to use it, but, in a nutshell:

A debugger will let you execute the code one instruction at a time, or one line at a time. It will let you run your code until a place you're interested in, then stop. While the code is stopped, you can inspect the values of the variables to make sure things are in order, and in some cases even modify things on the run to test various scenarios.

Some of the techniques of debugging without using a debugger are:

- print insertion, where you litter your code with printing commands that will allow you to track the state of your code while it is running,
- code reading, where you read the code and try to find the places where your intention differs from what is actually written
- mug conversations, where you try to explain your code to your friend (or a mug, or a penguin doll on your desk), and in the process see where your logic goes wrong
- binary cut search, where you delete chunks of your code at a time and see if the error is still present

and many more.

Comment: Thanks. That pretty much sums it up for me. I've debugged before but without the feature itself.

Comment: "mug conversations" I used to have a variation on this called the "expert idiot" technique. Friends would say, "This blows up at X and I don't know why." I would say, "OK, start from the beginning." and I would sit back and force them to explain *everything*, as if I were a complete idiot. Much of the time they would be in midsentence, pause, blush, and say, "Never mind." If they said, "Oh, it could never happen *there.*" I went into Pit Bull mode and forced them to defend every comma and semicolon because that "handwave" almost certainly meant they hadn't really looked at it.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging allows you to examine the values of variables at each step of your code's execution.  It is a good way to find stupid mistakes (among others).  For example, you might not catch this off-by-one error:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
    MethodThatShouldExecuteTenTimes(i);
}
```

If you step through your code with the debugger, you'll see that the method is called 11 times.

Answer (score 0):

If you write programs that always work first time, you will never need to find bugs.

If the program compiles, but doesn't work, how do you work out what's going wrong?

Adding lots of print statements works, but being able to step into functions, step through them and examine memory stores is really helpful.

One could say debugging is like violence - the last refuge of the incompentent!

But sometimes, we don't quite have the competence to avoid the bug, and a debugger makes life SOOOOOO much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging is the process of finding the code that is not doing what you want it to do. It is a very necessary skill in order to be efficient in getting work done. It can consist of many things. Including but not limited to:

- reading log files produced by the program
- viewing messages transmitted by your program across the network
- viewing the output of your program (e.g. does the web page display and act correctly)
- viewing the stack trace of an exception
- using the debugger to step through your code line by line so that you can see the values of variables at a specific point during execution.

The debugger can be used for more than just locating bugs in your program. It can aid you in understanding how existing code operates. You can set breakpoints in your code: a marker to tell the debugger to stop executing on that line. Then from that point you can begin stepping through your source code line by line.

In order to get a better feel for using the debugger, I recommend that you set a breakpoint in your code and step through it. You will then see exactly what I and others have said. What ever development environment you use should have instructions on how to use the included debugger.